# Как отправить картинку через функцию mail ?

Tags: php

Доброго времени друзья. У меня такой вопрос:
Я пытаюсь отправить файл через функцию mail php, я так понимаю файл изначально загружаться ко мне на сервер должен, а потом как прямая ссылка отправляться на почту?

Comment: Почта появилась гораздо раньше веба и имеет свои принципы пересылки контента, поэтому для пересылки прикрепленного изображения нужно включать его в тело письма. Это оправдано, учитывая что прочитать письмо могут уже после того, как сайт умрет/переродится/сервак вытерпит случайный rm -rf. В принципе, вы можете послать HTML-документ с обычной разметкой и ссылками, но не меньше половины рассылок включают все необходимые изображения в тело письма.  
Пример "как сделать" лежит здесь: http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Email-Using-Embedded-Images-in-HTML-Email-P113.html

Comment: Надеюсь, что кто-нибудь напишет человеческий пример чуть позже (еще больше надеюсь, что это буду я).

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал следующий код для отправки картинки в теле письма.

```
$picture[0] = "image.jpg"; //картинка для вставки в письмо
$to = "mymail@mail.ru"; //кому отправляем письмо
$thm = "Просто письмо"; //тема письма
$body = "test message"; //тело письма (html)

send_mail($to, $thm, $body, $picture);

function send_mail($mail_to, $thema, $html, $path)   
  {
    $EOL = "\n";
    $boundary     = "--".md5(uniqid(time()));
    $headers    = "MIME-Version: 1.0;$EOL";   
    $headers   .= "From: info@mail.ru$EOL";
    $headers   .= "Bcc: mymail@mail.ru$EOL";
    // Вложение отсутствует
    $headers   .= "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=\"$boundary\"$EOL";  

    $multipart  = "--{$boundary}$EOL";
    $multipart .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8$EOL";
    $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit$EOL";
    $multipart .= $EOL;
    $multipart .= str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $html);
    $multipart .= $EOL;

    if (!empty($path))
    {
      for($i = 0; $i < count($path); $i++)
      {
        $file = file_get_contents($path[$i]);
        $name = basename($path[$i]);
        $multipart .=  "$EOL--$boundary$EOL";   
        $multipart .= "Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=\"$name\"$EOL";
        $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64$EOL";
        // Вложение отсуствует
        // $multipart .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"$EOL"; 
        $multipart .= "Content-ID: <".md5($name).">$EOL";
        $multipart .= $EOL;
        $multipart .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file), 76, $EOL);
      }
    }

    $multipart .= "$EOL--$boundary--$EOL";   
    //echo $multipart;
    if(!mail($mail_to, $thema, $multipart, $headers))
      return False;
    else
      return True;  
    exit;  
  }
```